# How do I search Outlook messages for colons, spaces or parentheses?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, search

I have a few hundred messages that are all mostly identical. Each message has one of the following strings in the message body.

```
foo:1 (bar)
foo:2 (bar)
```

I would like to find all messages with the first string, but not the second.

I have tried everything I can think of in both the quick and advanced search functions in Outlook 2010. In particular, all of the following search terms return messages with `foo:2 (bar)`.

```
"foo:1 (bar)"
"foo:1"
"foo:1 "
"1 (bar)"
"1 "
"foo\:1"
"1 \(bar\)"
```

Here's an example screenshot showing what I'm talking about:

[image]

The two messages that are found both have message bodies corresponding to their subject lines.

How can I find these messages using Outlook search?

Comment: your screenshot shows Message not Subject ... consider showing us what the messages are, not what the subjects are.

Comment: @undrline-ReinstateMonica This question is seven years old. I'm no longer using Outlook 2010, I don't have access to this mailbox anymore, and I solved my problem manually seven years ago. But, as I said in the question, the bodies of the messages were the same as the subjects for the two sample messages. But my entire inbox was found as well, and I definitely did not have `foo:1 (bar)` in every inbox message.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Outlook search doesn't work, apparently, so I went through every message manually and categorized them by sight.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [Advanced Find](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/find-a-message-with-instant-search-HA102840067.aspx#_Use_Advanced_Find) (CTRL+SHIFT+F), using the Advanced Tab (pictured below), to search for special characters. Instant Search ignores special characters.

[image: Advanced Find Advanced Tab]

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I have tried using both instant and advanced search functions. Neither works.

Comment: The title makes the question sound like a "how to search for special characters" type question. It sounds like you're looking for messages that include A but not B. Assuming these values are known/constant, why not use Advanced Find's `Condition` field in the Advanced tab and search where "Contains='foo:1 (bar)'" and "Doesn't Contain='foo:2 (bar)'" ?

Comment: I am doing exactly that. Advanced Find is still coming back with messages that contain `foo:2 (bar)`.

Comment: If you don't believe me, [here's a screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/sM0RuJ8.png) Each message has a body with the corresponding subject in it, but you can see both are coming back in the search. More than that, everything in my Inbox is coming back. I assure you they don't ALL contain `foo:1 (bar)`.

Comment: @KrisHarper your screenshot shows Message not Subject ... consider showing us what the messages are.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
~="foo:1"
```

It's not obvious, but if you use quotes you can also precede them with a comparison operator. This comparison operator with the tilde means 'has this substring'.

You can also use more normal comparisons, like <, but they are not generally very useful.

Comment: I cannot find any reference for comparison operators in outlook search. Does anyone know of a decent list of all the operators available?

Comment: what version of outlook does `~="substring"` work in? I'm using 365 and it doesn't appear to work

Answer (score 1):

[using Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 Enterprise at my company,
Version 2008 (Build 13127.21348)]

Trythe following:

1. Within Outlook, select **Search** > **Search Tools** > **Advanced Find**
2. In the *Appointments and Meetings* tab *Search for the word(s):* field enter the word (including special characters) you are trying to find (e.g. *Training:*)
3. In the *More Choices* tab, select the **Match case** checkbox
4. Click the **Find now** button

This gave me the results I wanted. I was looking only for "training" events I had completed where I put "Training:" in the Subject. Using the Match case checkbox forced the search to include the colon.

Hope this helps!